# AndroidHttpClient debug request URI

Tags: android

Is it possible to Log.d() the actual URI string that AndroidHttpClient creates when HttpGet is used ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Using [AndroidHttpClient.enableCurlLogging( TAG, Log.DEBUG )](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html#enableCurlLogging%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) will log both the URI string and the request contents.